# AWS Cloudwatch DatabaseConnections metric differs to mysql Threads_connected

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In our mysql RDS database on AWS, I can see the number of database connections by going into CloudWatch Metrics and selecting the DatabaseConnections metric. It reports 13, which is as expected:

2 Docker containers containing our app are pointing to the database container. Each app has 2 database connections (read and write). Read connection has 5 threads in its connection pool in the database, write has 1. So 12 threads in the database's connection pool in total.

CloudWatch reports 13, not 12, but that's me connecting to the database to check its status.

However, when I connect to the database and run:

```
show status where `variable_name` like '%threads_connected%';
```

I get this:

```
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 17    |
+-------------------+-------+
```

That's 4 more than I expected. Where could the other 4 be coming from? This makes monitoring the database connections feel unreliable if mysql is telling me one thing and CloudWatch is telling me another.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try 'show processlist'

Comment: That just shows one item, which is me connecting to mysql through a console. All the connections being counted seem to include both in-use and idle connections

Comment: Not much info, but this.......  To monitor how many connections are in use, CloudWatch exposes a DatabaseConnections metric tracking open RDS connections, and MySQL exposes a similar Threads_connected metric counting connection threads. (MySQL allocates one thread per connection.) Either metric will help you monitor your connections in use, but the MySQL metric can be collected at higher resolution than the CloudWatch metric, which is reported at one-minute intervals. MySQL also exposes the Threads_running metric to isolate the threads that are actively processing queries.

Comment: link to above text   https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-rds-mysql-performance-metrics/#connection-metrics

Comment: Yeah, saw that, didn't tell me what I wanted. Unless it's something weird around Threads_connected's higher resolution.